# How to read files in HDFS directory using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read files inside a directory in HDFS using Python. I used below code but i am getting error.

**Code**:

```
cat = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/cloudera/CCMD"], stdout=PIPE)
```

**Error**:

```
cat: `/user/cloudera/CCMD': Is a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hrkpat.py", line 6, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(cat.stdout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    self._root = parser.close()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1254, in close
    self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

**Update:**

I am having 10-15 xml files in my **hdfs** directory that i want to parse. I am able to parse the xml when only one xml is present in the directory but as soon as i am having multiple number of files i am not able to parse the xml. For this use case i want to write python code so that i can parse one file from my directory and once i parse it move to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

you can use wildcard char `*` to read all files in dir:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/CCMD/*
```

Or just read xml files:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/CCMD/*.xml
```

Comment: It works if the directory is having one file, but when i am having multiple xml files in the directory it is throwing me error.
 `tree = ET.parse(cat.stdout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 12266, column 19
[cloudera@server ~]$ cat: Unable to write to output stream.
cat: Unable to write to output stream.`

Comment: reading all files from `hdfs` is fine using `*` but [see this](https://www.knowbigdata.com/page/hdfs-hadoop-fs-cat-error-unable-write-output-stream)

Comment: `hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/CCMD/*` this command will read all the files one by one or one at a time ?

Comment: output will be content of all files... so it reads all files in one time

Comment: you should use `for...loop` in python to read/process file(s) in that loop or MR with MultipleOutputFileForma as @franklinsijo suggested....

Comment: Can you share some examples or links for `MultipleOutputFileForma` it would help me.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ronak. Please upvote if you liked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is `cat: '/user/cloudera/CCMD': Is a directory`

You are trying to perform a file operation over a directory. Pass the path of a file to the command.

Use this command in `subprocess` instead,

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/CCMD/filename
```

Comment: file name can be different but the directory in which the file will be kept is same, that's why i want to give directory name instead of filename in the path.

Comment: There will be multiple files in my directory that i want to read, not a single file.

Comment: Then `hadoop fs -cat` is not your command. Either get a list of files in the hdfs directory and read them using the retrieved filenames. Buy why? Why are you trying to read files from hdfs? For next stage processing on the read data, if yes try writing MapReduce.

Comment: I am having some 10-15 XML's in HDFS that i want to parse using python. For that i need to parse them sequentially or one by one as i cannot merge the xml.

Comment: Why not download them to local with `hadoop dfs -get` and process them? If you want the output to be stored in hdfs then MapReduce is the solution.

Comment: there may be situation when the number of files could be 500 to 1000. I don't think downloading would be feasible that time.Eventually i want the output to be stored in hdfs.

Comment: Then using fsshell commands is not suitable for this case. You can try MR with MultipleOutputFileFormat.

Comment: Can you give any example of MultipleOutputFileFormat ?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886285/hadoop-mapreduce-one-output-file-for-each-input) would help :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. i am upvoting your answer as you helped me and explained properly. Please upvote my question if you find it good.

Comment: Updated my post please check.

Comment: I have one question my xml size is 489 kb so is it advisable to parse it in hadoop environment or parse it locally ?

Comment: 489KB is very small when we are dealing with HDFS. You can process this locally!

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo